# Getting a specific complete build from TFS

Tags: tfs

There is one particular change I am testing. This is ChangeSet: 123456 (let us assume). I need to get the complete solution as on the data that changeset was checked in.

If I do Get Specific Version -> By ChangeSet: 123456, I get only those files that were affected by the change set. I am unable to get the entire project.

Please help.

Comment: TFS optimizes this because it knows that you have all the other files locally.  Eg, if you have previously done a get of changeset 12, and you do a get specific version of changeset 45, only the files different between those changesets will be downloaded.  If you have done something to these files locally (say, deleted them) and not told TFS about what you've done, this optimization will obviously fail.  Ewald's suggestion to use "force" below would be appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to the source control explorer, you can select the root folder of the project and do a "Get specific version". It will do a get of all the files that are not locally of the correct version yet.

You can force to get all the files by clicking the other option to get all the files in that dialog.